# UIPopoverControllerDelegate delegate methods not being called

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uipopovercontroller, popover, dismiss

I have a screen with a button. Clicking the button will display a popover with two buttons. I want to be able to use the following method when the popover is dismissed:

```
#pragma mark - UIPopoverControllerDelegate
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
NSLog(@"OrderViewController.m -popoverControllerDidDismissPopover start");
}
```

The popover view has its own class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MenuItemModel.h"

@interface SelectedItemsOptionsViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak) id <UIPopoverControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MenuItemModel *item;

@end
```

The class which creates the popover has:

```
@interface OrderViewController : UIViewController <PageViewControllerDelegate,                                        
UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ServiceConnectorDelegate,
UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
```

So the OrderViewController - wants to know when SelectedItemsOptionsViewController has been dismissed.

I have the method declared (first block of code) and I am setting the delegate as:

```
SelectedItemsOptionsViewController *destViewController = (SelectedItemsOptionsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

popSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;

[destViewController setDelegate:self];
destViewController.item = toDisplay;
```

So I am setting the delegate OK as far as i'm aware... the delegate property is @syntheized in th SelectedItemsOptionsViewController.m and well, its driving me a bit crazy.

Comment: How are you dismissing your popover?

Comment: Just by tapping anywhere on the screen that is not covered by the popup. (I am not doing it programatically, i read that this will not call the dismissal)

Comment: Same problem. Ever solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I could be misunderstanding something here but looks like you're assigning the delegate for a UIViewController class, but where are you assigning the popOver its delegate, in the storyboard?